# C# replace anchor text

Tags: c#, regex, replace, anchor

Some of the links that get inputted to our database are HUGE and I need to control it as it's breaking reports.

I need to programmatically transform:

```
<a href="http://www.thisismylongurl.com">http://www.thisismylongurl.com</a>
```

Into

```
<a href="http://www.thisismylongurl.com">Link</a>
```

I have looked into Regex.Replace, but can't seem to find one off the shelf which does what I need.

In case it's not obvious, "http://www.thisismylongurl.com" will be a different URL every time, so I need to use a Regex instead of a fixed string replacement.

Comment: I'd use an HTML parser instead, tbh.

Comment: "Link" will be constant for every url??

Comment: I mean this part -  ">Link</a>" will be same for all url??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When "Link" in the replacement does not change you can try this

```
(<\s*a\s+href="[^"]+">)[^<]*(?=</a>)
```

and replace with

```
$1Link
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?34fho)

`\s` is matching a whitespace character

`[^"]` is a negated character class that matches any character but the `"`

`(?=</a>)` is a positive lookahead insertion, that ensures, that `</a>` is following the match.

`$1` gives you the content of the first capturing group, that is, what is matched by the subpattern following the first opening bracket.

Comment: or you could use positive lookbehind assertion, so you don't need the `$1` ;)

Comment: @Nolonar, you are right, but .net is the only language that accept infinite length lookbehinds. Therefore I wanted it to keep a bit more general.

Comment: This works absolutely beautifully. Thank you very much this has saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Works perfect. No Regex Involved though.

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string str1="<a href='http://www.thisismylongurl.com'>http://www.thisismylongurl.com</a>";
        int b1 = str1.IndexOf(">");
        int b2 = str1.LastIndexOf("<");
        str1= str1.Remove(b1+1);
        int b3 = str1.IndexOf(">");
        str1 = str1.Insert(b3+1, "Link");
        Response.Write(str1);
    }
```